# drop down on hover inside of mobile drop down menu

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, navbar

To whom who can help,

I followed a video tutorial on how to create a navbar with a drop down menu when hovering over 'work' in navbar. I was able to get this part, but the video tutorial did not explain how to do the same when in mobile view if I were to click 'work' within the mobile drop down menu and now im pretty lost.

Can anyone help figure out what I should be adding within my code to be able to hover over 'work' within drop down to view the same li's  being mapped?

(or should it be click because you cant hover a mouse pointer when using an iphone while viewing general drop downs on websites?)

- live site: https://visionary-belekoy-9a3354.netlify.app/
- repo code: https://github.com/DeBoer753/cbm-APP
- stack over flow code (below): I have NavBar2 js and css if helpful to look at. If not necessary, I have the drop down js and css below that.

NAVBAR2 JSX

```
// REACT:
import { useState } from 'react'

// ROUTER:
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

// COMPONENTS:
import DropDown from './DropDown'

//IMGS:
// import logoIcon from '../../imgs/CBMedia_White.png' -- netlify told you to get rid of es lint errors in order to deploy, buy you might need this. Keep that in mind

// CSS:
import './NavBar2.css' 

// NAVBAR2:
export default function NavBar2() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false)
  const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState(false)

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click)
  const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false)

  const onMouseEnter = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 960) {
      setDropdown(false)
    } else {
      setDropdown(true)
    }
  }

  const onMouseLeave = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 960) {   
      setDropdown(false)
    } else {
      setDropdown(false)
    }
  }

  return (
    <>

      <nav className='navbar'>

        <div className='logoBox'>
          <Link to='/' className='navbar-logo'>Chris Blossom Media</Link>
        </div>

        <div className='menu-icon' onClick={handleClick}>
          <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
        </div>

        <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
          <li className='nav-item'><Link to='/services' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu }>Services</Link></li>
          <li className='nav-item' onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}><Link to='/work' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu }>Work <i className='fas fa-caret-down'/></Link>{dropdown && <DropDown />}</li>
          <li className='nav-item'><Link to='/reviews' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu }>Reviews</Link></li>
          <li className='nav-item'><Link to='/about' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu }>About</Link></li>
          <li className='nav-item'><Link to='/contact' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu }>Contact</Link></li>
        </ul>

      </nav>

    </>
)
}
```

NAVBAR2 CSS

```
/* NAVBAR ----------------> */
.navbar {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(28, 27, 27) 0%, rgb(26, 23, 23) 100%);
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.logoBox {
  width: 45%;
}

.navbar-logo {
  color: #fff;
  align-self: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 400px;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}


.mobileShow img {
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.fa-firstdraft {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70vw;
  justify-content: end;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.nav-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 80px;
}

.nav-links {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.nav-links:hover {
  background: rgb(173, 173, 173);
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.fa-bars {
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-links-mobile {
  display: none;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .navbar {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  .NavbarItems {
    position: relative;
  }

  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: -180%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }

  .nav-menu.active {
    background: #242222;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-left: 0px;
  }

  .nav-links {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }

  .nav-links:hover {
    background: rgb(173, 173, 173);
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  .logoBox {
    width: 90%;
  }

  .navbar-logo {
    /* position: absolute; */
    top: 0;
    left: -75px;
    transform: translate(25%, 50%);
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 5px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .fa-times {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .nav-links-mobile {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 80%;
    background: #1888ff;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .nav-links-mobile:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #1888ff;
    transition: 250ms;
  }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
.navbar-logo {
  font-size: 22px;
}
}
```

DROPDOWN JSX

```
// REACT:
import { useState } from 'react'

// ROUTER:
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

// DATA:
import { MenuItems } from './MenuItems' // this deconstructs and finds the variable holding the data

// CSS:
import './DropDown.css' 

export default function DropDown() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(false)

  const handleClick = () => setClick(!click)

  return (
    <>
      <ul onClick={handleClick} className={click ? 'dropdown-menu clicked' : 'dropdown-menu'}>
        {MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}><Link className={item.cName} to={item.path} onClick={() => setClick(false)}>{item.title}</Link></li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}
```

DROPDOWN CSS

```
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  right: 260px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: start;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(28, 27, 27) 0%, rgb(26, 23, 23) 100%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover {
  background: rgb(173, 173, 173);
}

.dropdown-menu.clicked {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you point out, on a mobile device you wont have a cursor, so you'll have to deal with it differently. You likely want it to open when clicked and close again when clicked a second time. The can use 'useState' to store whether or not the menu is currently open.

EDIT: There are packages that can help responding to screen changes, like [react-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive).